# Error while connecting to discord WebSocket on specific platform

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, discord, cross-platform

I'm trying to connect to Discord using the [Gateway API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway) in a React Native app. It connects normally on iOS and Web platforms, but on Android, it refuses to connect with the following error:

```
ERROR  WebSocket error: {"isTrusted": false, "message": "Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'"}
LOG  WebSocket closed: {"code": 1006, "isTrusted": false, "reason": "Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'"}
```

My code:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bot ${botToken}`,
      "User-Agent": "DiscordBot/1.0 (https://example.com)",
    };
    fetch("https://discord.com/api/gateway/bot", { headers })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const ws = new WebSocket(`${data.url}/?v=10&encoding=json`);

        let payload = {
          op: 2,
          d: {
            token: botToken,
            intents: 33281,
            properties: {
              os: "foo",
              browser: "f",
              device: "foo",
            },
          },
        };

        ws.onopen = () => {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
          console.log("WebSocket connected");
        };

        ws.onerror = (error) => {
          console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
        };

        ws.onclose = (event) => {
          console.log("WebSocket closed:", event);
        };
        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          const newMsg = data.d.content;

          if (data.t === "MESSAGE_CREATE") {
            console.log(newMsg);
          }
        };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Expected it to work on all platforms but it connects only on Web (expo), iOS, and errors out on Android.